# Proper way of closing a unix socket

Tags: c, unix-socket

I am using this code that I got from [this link](http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/netguide/dusockT.code_samples.html):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define DATA "Hello world"


int main()
{
  int sock;
  struct sockaddr_un server;

  sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sock < 0) {
      perror("opening stream socket");
      exit(1);
  }

  server.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  strcpy(server.sun_path, "/tmp/foo.sock");

  int con = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
  if (con < 0) {
      close(sock);
      perror("connecting stream socket");
      exit(1);
  }

  const char * D = "Hello world!";
  if (write(sock, DATA, sizeof(DATA)) < 0)
      perror("writing on stream socket");

  close(sock);

  // QUESTION
  // close(con);   // should I include this line?

  return 0;
}
```

This code works as long as there is a server listening for data.

**Anyways my question is** should I also close the connection `con` as `close(con);` at the end?

If it turns out you do have to close the connection then this proves you should not copy and paste code from the internet. I just want to make sure I have no memory leaks with this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> should I also close the connection `con` as `close(con);` at the end?

No, because that's not a "connection". Take a look at [`man 2 connect`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html):

> RETURN VALUE
>
> If the connection or binding succeeds, zero is returned. On error, -1 is returned, and `errno` is set appropriately.

Your `con` is jut the return value of `connect`, so it's either `0` for success or `-1` for error. It is not a file descriptor, therefore you should not attempt to close it.

I would suggest you to rename the variable (e.g. to `res`) or to just check inside the `if` condition:

```c
if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) == -1) {
    close(sock);
    perror("connecting stream socket");
    exit(1);
}
```

> I just want to make sure I have no memory leaks with this code.

You won't in any case. All file descriptors are automatically closed by the operating system when your program finishes running. If you open a file descriptor (like your `sock`) and use it all the way until the end of the program, it isn't even necessary to `close()` it (though it's good practice). The standard input, standard output and standard error file descriptors are usually never closed by normal programs.

Answer (score 3):

`connect()` returns 0 (on success) or -1 (on error), not a connection. Closing 0 closes your program's `stdin`. Closing -1 is an error that will have no further consequences. In either case, you should *not* close `con`.

Comment: `errno == EBADF` after an attempt to close `-1`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sure, but other than that, it will not cause any consequences.

Comment: Correct — that call to `close()` fails but does no other damage, unless you count setting `errno` to a non-zero value as 'damage'.